# jekyll markdown internal links

Tags: markdown, jekyll

Jekyll uses Markdown-formatted links, but how can I link to internal content?

```
[[link]]
```

Answer (score 288):

You can now post internal links by using the following:

```
[Some Link]({% post_url 2010-07-21-name-of-post %})
```

This is also referenced in the [Jekyll Documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#linking-to-posts).

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/pull/369

Comment: Any idea how to internally link to a page?

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to link to a page. This PR was closed without being merged: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/369

Comment: Is it possible to get the title to show easily, e.g. render to `[Title of post](/correct/permalink)` with a single command? I could only do it with filtering which is too verbose.

Comment: If you have subdirs: [Link's Text]({% post_url /dirname/2010-07-21-post %})

Comment: Just a small note: do not include the extension in 2010-07-21-name-of-post.

Comment: This worked fine for me `[pivot]({% post_url 2015-02-03-pivot.md %})` -- using `post_url` as well as the file extension.

Answer (score 75):

It is now possible to link to pages other than posts using the `link` tag. `link` works for posts, pages, documents in a collection, and files.

```
{{ site.baseurl }}{% link _collection/name-of-document.md %}
{{ site.baseurl }}{% link _posts/2016-07-26-name-of-post.md %}
{{ site.baseurl }}{% link news/index.html %}
{{ site.baseurl }}{% link /assets/files/doc.pdf %}
```

Remember to include the file extension when using the `link` tag.
To use it to create a link:

```
[Link to a document]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link _collection/name-of-document.md %})
[Link to a post]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link _posts/2016-07-26-name-of-post.md %})
[Link to a page]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link news/index.html %})
[Link to a file]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link /assets/files/doc.pdf %})
```

See [Jekyll Documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#links).

Comment: I also found this documentation page helpful - https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#link

Comment: I've just found that there is no need to use `{{ site.baseurl }}` since it doubles baseurl value in the generated href. `[Link to a post]({% link _posts/2016-07-26-name-of-post.md %})`

Comment: You need to use site.baseurl on Jekyll 3.x, it is no longer needed in 4.x. But Pages is still stuck on 3.x as the max version, AFAIK.

Answer (score 26):

For pages, [they decided not to add a `page_url` tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1407#issuecomment-22439584) because you'd have to know the path of the page anyway. So you just have to link to it manually:

```
[My page](/path/to/page.html)
```

Or you can do something big and ugly like this if you want to programatically get the title of the page:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% if page.url == '/path/to/page.html' %}
[{{ page.title }}]({{ page.url }})
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As another answer has noted, there is the `{% link ... %}` tag which is recommended to be used, as it helps ensure links are made correctly, and it will give you an error if a link is broken. See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#link

Answer (score 26):

If the *internal content* is on the same page then it is possible to link to it using the `auto_ids` feature. You enable this in `_config.yml`:

```
kramdown:
    auto_ids: true
```

With this enabled each heading gets an `id` ref based on the heading text. For example

```
### My Funky Heading
```

will become

```
<h3 id="my-funky-heading">My Funky Heading</h3>
```

You can link to this from within the same document by doing something like this:

```
The funky text is [described below](#my-funky-heading)
```

You can assign an explicit id if you prefer:

```
### My Funky Heading
{: #funky }
```

and link to it

```
The funky text is [described below](#funky)
```

Comment: That works even if you want to reference other elements than titles.

Comment: This can also be extended for links in other pages. e.g.: [text] (/path/to/file/#funky)

Comment: Note that the `kramdown` `auto_ids` feature is [true by default](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html) so you have it enabled as long as you don't explicitly _disable_ it `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways of linking in Jekyll, some of which are now outdated.

#### With link tags

The recommended way to link to internal files is

```
[Link]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link path/to/file.md %})
```

Note that this will cause an error if the file moves or gets deleted.

#### With permalinks

To link to a page without causing errors (broken links instead):

```
[Link]({{ '/path/to/page/' | relative_url }})
```

Note that here you need to know the permalink of the page and pass it through the `relative_url` filter to ensure that it is prefixed with the base url of the site.

The permalink of a page depends on the `permalink` setting in your config file and the `permalink` key in the front matter of the file.

#### With jekyll-relative-links

If you want to use relative paths (and want the links to work in GitHub's markdown view), you should use [`jekyll-relative-links`](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links). This lets you write links like:

```
[Link](./path/to/file.md)

[Link to file in parent folder](../file.md)
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this is your project directory:

[image: project directory]

To link "index.md" to a file inside folder "blog" called "20190920-post1.md", do the following:

1. Open the file "index.md".
2. Add the following:

   [any text](./relative path)

For example:

```
- [Sept 20th 2019 - Kikucare's Journey](./blog/20190920-post1.md)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What if Jekyll then keeps the link to the `.md` file and does not convert `.md` to `.html`? -- Then the plugin https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links should be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Working in Jekyll 3.9.x:

In HTML:
`<a href="{{ '/blog/' | relative_url }}">Link to blog</a>`

Answer (score 0):

## Sep 2023

Since Jekyll doesn't know which post you want to include, you need to include the full file name.
You do not need to include the extension.

**Date alert**
*Notice that the filename and the date category that output inside the `<p>` tag are different. That is because the post has a different date in the Front Matter. When the page renders to HTML, it looks at the Front Matter date.*

```html
{% post_url 2023-09-28-test-page %}

<!-- outputs this -->
<p>/2023/01/02/test-page.html</p>
```

### To display a proper URL

You need to wrap the Liquid with brackets `(` and `)` and use `[` `]` to include your anchor text.

```html
[A Test Page]({% post_url 2023-09-28-test-page %})

<!-- outputs this -->
<p><a href="/2023/01/02/test-page.html">A Test Page</a></p>
```

### Rename a file after linking

If you rename your post file after linking, Jekyll will throw an error.

```
Error: Could not find post "2023-09-28-test-page" in tag 'post_url'. 
Make sure the post exists and the name is correct.
Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

### Include an attribute

You can use curly brackets to include your attributes. Notice the colon at the beginning.

```html
[A Test Page]({% post_url 2023-09-28-test-page %}){:target="_blank"}

<!-- outputs this -->
<p><a href="/2023/01/02/test-23-page.html" target="_blank">A Test Page</a></p>
```

### Include multiple attributes

To include more attributes, you can add them like regular HTML attributes followed by a space.

```html
[A Test Page]({% post_url 2023-09-28-test-page %}){:target="_blank" class="active"}

<!-- outputs this -->
<p><a href="/2023/01/02/test-23-page.html" target="_blank" class="active">A Test Page</a></p>
```