# How to set up project pages as subpages of GitHub personal webpage?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

My github personal webpage is `davidrpugh.github.io`. I have set up a subpage for my software projects at `davidrpugh.github.io/software` and created stub subpages for each of my software projects. Example would be `davidrpugh.io/software/pypwt`.

Question: How do I set up the project webpage, which would by default live at `davidrpugh.io/pypwt`, so that it lives instead at `davidrpugh.io/software/pypwt`? I also want any updates to the project webpage to automatically render on my personal webpage as well.

I am guessing that this is a solved problem, and I am not using the correct set of search terms.

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. This question definitely relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I was a bit perplexed by the down vote (particularly given that no explanation was left).

Comment: Clear! Connecting user/organization github pages with project pages is a touchy problem that deserves some exploration and documentation. That's why I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning you project web site hosted at https://github.com/davidrpugh/penn-world-tables in gh-pages branch.

```
#Jekyll config
url : http://davidrpugh.github.io 
baseurl: /penn-world-tables
```

The complete site url will be http://davidrpugh.github.io/penn-world-tables.
You will not be able to change this at all. If you try to set a `permalink: software/pypwt/` on the index page it will give you http://davidrpugh.github.io/penn-world-tables/software/pypwt/

In order to get a http://davidrpugh.github.io/software/pypwt/ url you can

- host you pypwt doc on you user site, as it is done actually
- create a https://github.com/davidrpugh/software repository that will have a http://davidrpugh.github.io/software/ url
- leave the idea to have a /software/pypwt url and logically host pypwt doc in penn-world-tables repository.
  The http://davidrpugh.github.io/penn-world-tables/ is not so bad after all, although it breaks the correlation between navigating in software/pypwt and getting the http://davidrpugh.github.io/penn-world-tables/ url. I think that it's not a great ergonomy / accessibility problem.

Just use the same template over all you repositories, this will make user fills like it's the same site when navigating.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Particularly your third bullet point. I will try it out and see how it works/feels.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're finding your current method difficult because you're using *pages* (http:// jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) instead of *posts* (http:// jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/).

You have 2 solutions:

## Solution 1 (You probably already know this one)

You can either continue to use pages, and simply write each new post at `/software/<name of post>/index.md`

## Solution 2 (Difficult, but easier in long run)

You can use posts and write each new post in `/_posts/<YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title>.md` and set the category in the Front Matter (http:// jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) to "software".

Based on your `_config.yml` it will save these posts in `/:categories/:title/` (in this case `/software/pypwt.html`).

You can then link to these posts using (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195560/3158248) to ensure links don't get broken if you update your `_config.yaml`

Comment: I am aware of the difference between pages and posts. I intend to use this feature to write posts about new features of my various projects as they become available. I suppose this means that I will need to give up my original organization plan for my website.