# Internal links in Jekyll using Org mode

Tags: emacs, jekyll, org-mode

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629675/jekyll-markdown-internal-links) about linking to internal content using markdown. How can I link to other posts using Org mode?

I tried the markdown format and I get the following error:

```
...error:
             Error: Unknown tag 'post'
             Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a relative URL to another blog post inside a jekyll post with `{% post_url 1025-08-26-blog-post-name %}` (with no trailing `.html` or `.org` on the post name).

To actually make it a link, you'll need to wrap it in an html link. Assuming you've got your org-publish settings set up to write HMTL, this can be a little tricky, since it seems that the standard org-mode link syntax doesn't work properly for jekyll-inserted links. Instead, you can just insert the anchor html directly into your org file using an org-mode HTML escape:

`Blah blah surrounding text
@@html:<a href="{% post_url 1025-08-26-blog-post-name %}">@@Text describing link to my other post@@html:</a>@@ more surrounding text`

Comment: Brilliant! `<a href="{% post_url 1025-08-26-blog-post-name %}">@@Text describing link to my other post@@html:</a>`